# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/layouts/Navbar' in '/opt/build/repo/src'

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I am trying to deploy a react project on netlify and I keep getting these error
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/layouts/Navbar' in '/opt/build/repo/src'`.
I tried depolying on vercel I still get the same error.
Please how do I resolve it.

```
// import Navbar from "./components/layouts/Navbar";
import Navbar from "./components/layouts/Navbar"
import Footer from "./components/layouts/Footer";
import Alert from "./components/layouts/Alert";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import User from "./pages/User";
import About from "./pages/About";
import NotFound  from "./pages/NotFound";
import { GitHubProvider } from "./components/context/github/GithubContext";
import { AlertProvider } from "./components/context/alert/AlertContext";

function App() {
  return (
    <GitHubProvider>
      <AlertProvider>
        <Router>
          <div className="flex flex-col justify-between h-screen ">
            <Navbar />
            <main className="container mx-auto px-3 pb-12">
              <Alert />
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                <Route path="/user/:login" element={<User />} />
                <Route path="/notfound" element={<NotFound />} />
                <Route path="/*" element={<NotFound />} />
              </Routes>
            </main>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </AlertProvider>
    </GitHubProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Checkout the Netlify error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypauc.png)

Comment: You should post a screenshot of your directory, because we need to see if "./components/layouts/Navbar" is written correctly or not

Answer (score 1):

I think yo've changed `Navbar` folder name from `navbar` to `Navbar` and git didn't understand it, try Changing Navbar folder name to Something else like NavigationBar and push your code on your repo i think it might fix it.

Comment: Thank you Eisa, that was what exactly happened. I had to clear my git cache and then make a new commit.